# How to push an UIViewController to UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to push an `UINavigationController` object into an `UISplitViewController`, but I got the message below:

```
2014-04-30 02:25:11.215 test_demo[483:70b] Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller <UINavigationController: 0x8d34360>.
```

This is my push method:

```
- (IBAction)toggleToSplitView:(id)sender {
    SplitViewController *splitViewController = [[SplitViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:splitViewController animated:YES];
}
```

In fact, I want to design a login view with a `UIViewController`, then, I want to push to a `UISplitViewController`. Anyone who can help me to solve this problem? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man. I don't think this is a good idea to push an UIViewController to UISplitViewController. if you must to do it like this. you can use this method:

```
SplitViewController *splitViewController = [[SplitViewController alloc] init];
[self.view.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];
```

but, I think this is not a perfect solution. Especially， when you need to add some custom animation during push between different ViewController. thus, maybe you should custom a splitView and added it to  an UIViewController. there are many sample code in github for custom UISplitViewController.

https://github.com/Alterplay/APSplitViewController

https://github.com/palaniraja/cUISplitViewController

I hope this help for you.

Comment: thank you for your help. this is a good answer. my program worked.

Comment: How to close the SplitViewController when I want to quit it and return back to previous window?

Answer (score 1):

As the message suggests, you cannot do that.

What you can do is display your `SplitViewController` first and then present your `LoginView` from your `SplitViewController` without animation.

Comment: I try to setup animation to NO, but I also got the same error.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. When you start your app, you show the `LoginView` first, right ?  Try showing your `SplitViewController` instead first. Then in the `viewDidAppear` of your  `SplitViewController `, add the line that will present the `LoginView` : `[self presentViewController:self.loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];`

Comment: I need to display the login View Controller first, and then toggle to a split view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're trying to push a `UISplitViewController` into `UINavigationController` object. Not vice versa. And it's not allowed. That's what error message says.

`UISplitViewController` is a specific controller which can be used only as a root view controller in the navigation stack. Also, it can be used only in iPad applications.

Comment: yes, you are right. I understand the UISplitViewController must as a root view Controller. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)pushView :(UIViewController *)splitViewController{
    self.rootViewControllerPre=self.window.rootViewController;
    _window.rootViewController=splitViewController;
}

-(void)popView{
    _window.rootViewController=_rootViewControllerPre;
}
```